# python app setup option from cPanel software section is missing

Tags: python, django, cpanel

I bought a domain and hosting from webhost python for my Django web site but python app setup option from cPanel software section is missing and, in every tutorial, they follow the same the step means without python app setup option I have no way to live my Django site, I am completely new in web development and this first time I want live my website[image: as you see in my software section python app setup option is missing]

I try to follow my YouTube tutorial, but everyone follows same steps so don't understand what should i do

Comment: that means that the hosting company that you bought from them has the python application disabled you should contact them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.